# "Should" versus "would"

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs, should

The NOAD reports the following notes about *should* and *would*:

> The traditional rule is that *should* is used with first person pronouns (*I* and *we*), as in *I said I should be late*, and *would* is used with second and third persons (*you*, *he*, *she*, *it*, *they*), as in *you didn't say you would be late*. In practice, however, *would* is normally used instead of *should* in reported speech and conditional clauses: *I said I would be late*; *if we had known, we would have invited her*.

I thought that *should* and *would* really had a slightly different meaning. Am I wrong?

Comment: Not an answer but I seem to remember being taught the future, conditional and imperative cases for "would" and "should". Just wish I could remember what they were. We were told that it is very important in legal documents.

Comment: The traditional rule for should as given by you means would. But that usage is British. "I should go, if I were you". in AmE would be: "I would go if I were you." AmE does not use should to mean would. **No one here has bothered to mention this fact**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Smirkingman's answer is right but unhelpful. There are historically two *different* uses of "should", and kiamaluno is asking about the other one.

In older works you will find writers generally use "I/we should" where today most of us would write (and say) "I/we would", i.e. without any sense of obligation.

This is separate from the obligatory sense that smirkingman describes, and has no meaning different from "would".

There is a parallel with "shall" and "will" (and historically, "should" and "would" were the past tense of these): "Shall" has a sense of command - little used in speech today, but very much alive in legal documents and technical specifications; but for speakers of many varieties of English it is quite normal to say "I shall" as an alternative to "I will". For me at least "Shall I?" is the normal question form: I would only say "Will I?" when asking for a prediction.

Comment: +! for "shall" in legal and technical documents

Comment: should for would is marked as British usage: I should leave now, if I were you. BrE.

Answer (score 8):

The trouble here is that *should* has many meanings depending on the context.

- It can imply obligation

  > You should check your oil level.
- It can imply probability

  > He should have finished checking the oil level by now.
- It can represent a condition

  > If I should run out of oil, what then?
- It is the past tense of shall [but note the requirement of a missed obligation]

  > I told him he should have checked his oil level.

Nowadays, as your NOAD quote says, *would* is used where *should* used to be.

Consider "I should like a new car." This is valid but sounds old-fashioned. Here the use of *should* implies a kind of politeness: you're not presuming that you deserve a new car. Nowadays you'd more likely hear "I would like a new car" or the contracted "I'd like a new car."

Comment: I guess that _would_ doesn't imply obligation. I would not say _you would check your oil level_. I also give to _I would not say that_ a different meaning than to _I should not say that_.

Comment: In what sense does *"I told him he should have checked his oil level"* have the past tense of *shall*?

Answer (score 2):

'**should**' implies that a constraint or obligation is anticipated:

> I said I should be late.

It implies that there is something inhibiting my being on time or that I'll deliberately choose to be late.

'**would**' implies a degree of certainty:

> I said I would be late.

I'm going to be late and that's it.

'**could**' implies possibility:

> I said I could be late.

I'll try to be on time, but something might happen to prevent me.

Comment: I'm not sure about 'should' implying something inhibiting you in the context of being late, that fits 'could' much better. However, if you change the sentence to 'I should be *on time*', it makes sense.

Comment: @elendil agree usually, but I was thinking of the construction "I said I should be late (you know what Anna's like, she always got some last-minute thing to solve)" = I foresee that Anna will delay my leaving a preceding engagement.

Comment: Surely that would be 'I said I *would* be late'? nowadays? In other words, I said I would definitely be late given a delaying factor. The problem here is that 'should' has so many meanings: 'ought to', likelihood, past tense shall, a consequence etc. EDIT: In fact, the NOAD entry quoted above says just that: should is traditional with 'I' and 'we', would is more modern.

Comment: @elendil Indeed, but I'm OLD >;-)

Answer (score -2):

*Should* expresses a condition, an obligation, futurity, or probability.
*Would* expresses a possibility, an intention, a desire, a custom or a request.