# "Looking forward to watching me play" vs "watching me playing"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

We were reading a piece of text and my English teacher told us that the sentence:

> "For sure, my fans are looking forward to watching me play today."

is wrong, and that it should instead be written as

> "... looking forward to watching me playing today."

Because the word "to" in the phrase "looking forward to" is a preposition, thus only a noun clause/phrase should follow, and since "play" is a predicate objective the former sentence ("... watching me play ...") is wrong.

I'm 99% sure that "... watching me play" is the correct one, but my lack of grammatical knowledge stops me from being 100% sure.

Could anyone explain how the sentence "works"/the grammatical workings behind these?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [infinitive or gerund](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262893/infinitive-or-gerund) Or ['Should've seen it glow' or 'should've seen it glowing'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53106/shouldve-seen-it-glow-or-shouldve-seen-it-glowing)

Comment: From the first duplicate: << _[W]hat they most dread is to see it end._

Can someone explain to me why it is written ''to see it end'' rather than ''to see it ending''?

From the same category I've got ''to see him leave'' rather than ''to see him leaving''. Why  this use of the infinitive? >> ... << They're both fine. _See_, along with other sense verbs, allow[s] either infinitive (without to) or gerund complements; speaker's choice, no real meaning difference. – John Lawler >> ... << I believe there is small difference in meaning.  {Anton} >>

Comment: See also [Non-finite clause complementation of complex-transitive verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114365/non-finite-clause-complementation-of-complex-transitive-verbs/114389#114389) (J Lawler's answer).