# Degree of Potentiality: Would vs. Should: Which indicates a greater possibility?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditionals, should, mood, would

People in my new workplace hold that "should" is less definitive than "would," for e.g., in the sentence:

Commodity prices could be depressed in 2016 due to oversupply, which *should* pressure power prices.

To me, "should" here indicates a certainty (that oversupply has a relation to power prices) given some condition (that has been (naturally) left unsaid).

Which word/verb/mood of the two is more preferable if the author's intention is to play safe?

Answer (score 1):

> Commodity prices could be depressed in 2016 due to oversupply, which **should** pressure power prices.

In the above, there is some uncertainty around the power prices. It is expected to happen (it should), but one cannot be certain.

> Commodity prices could be depressed in 2016 due to oversupply, which **would** pressure power prices.

With `would`, there is a certainty.  Oversupply *would* pressure power prices.  No uncertainty except for commodity prices themselves.

That said, if you want to clearly allow for uncertainty:

> Commodity prices could be depressed in 2016 due to oversupply, which **might** pressure power prices.

It is a bit more complicated if you consider alternate definitions of the two as posted here: ["Should" versus "would"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10066/should-versus-would)

Comment: Thank you Minnow! My understanding was that *would* also carries uncertainty. Ref: your para2, wouldn't *will* be better instead of *would* if we wanted a word to convey certainty (which we don't)? Gawrsh.

Comment: Yes, I agree using *will* does evoke more certainty.